# How to onChange event method pass additional parameter by React hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I need to output modified value. Say I'm inputting: hello world, and I need this result: "hello world" (with quotation marks). I can do it with class-component but I failed with Hooks. What is wrong in my code?

```js
const { useState } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState('');

  const onChange = (a, b, event) => {
    setUser(a + event.target.value + b);
  };

  return (
    <form>
      <h3>Username is: {user}</h3>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={user}
        onChange={onChange.bind(null, '"', '"')} />
    </form>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've updated your code block to make it a runnable Stack Snippet. It seems to work (in terms of binding more information to the event handler). What specifically is the problem you're having?

Comment: For next time, here's how to do that snippet yourself: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/.

Answer (score 2):

```
When you use arrow functions there is no need to bind.
```

```js
 const   onChange = (val)=>{
    console.log(val)// comment
    }

    <input type="text"
       onChange={() => onChange("comment")}
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

### PROBLEM

Since `onChange` runs on every keypress, you're attaching the `quotation` marks to every keypress.

### SOLUTION

Rather than putting your quotation marks on your state. Attach the quotation marks in your JSX.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState('');

  const onChange = (event) => {
    setUser(event.target.value)
  };

  return (
    <form>
      <h3>Username is: {user ? `"${user}"`: ''}</h3>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={user}
        onChange={onChange} />
    </form>
  );
};
export default App;
```

passing extra arguments from input field

```
<input
   onChange={e => onChange(e, 'hello, 'world')}
/>
```

Comment: What the OP's code does works (and in a fairly similar way: creates a new function with some arguments bound to it).

Comment: Thanks. it works, but is it possible without passing an anonymous function into jsx?

Comment: yes, thanks, but as a said: is it possible without passing an anonymous function into jsx? just binding?

Comment: Yeah. But I see no reason using the bind function here. You `onChange` function just needs the `event` from the input field. You could use the function directly.

Comment: ok, please give me your binding example. because this is very simplified example, it is just an idea

Comment: Why do you need to use the `bind` method?

Comment: I do not need bind(). I need to pass additional parameters into hendleInput (). if you know how to do it without bind() then please give me an example. this is how I did it with class-component:

class App extends Component {
state = { title: 'Main Title' };
hendleInput = (val_1, val_2, event) => {
this.setState({
 title: val_1 + event.target.value + val_2,});};
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3> {this.state.title} </h3>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.hendleInput.bind(this, 'Your coment is: "', '"')} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Comment: @DevNewUser check it again.

Comment: What does not work? Can you create a reproducible issue [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ydkjsy)? Do copy your code there and let me see.

Comment: ok very simply: can you please convert (just convert) this class-component to functional component? do not change any logic. just convert with Hooks.

code: https://react-xsnnvy.stackblitz.io/

img: https://ibb.co/sJ4jKTn

Comment: check this out -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ydkjsy

Comment: no, this does not works. this is class-componet. cant't update upper coment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-b5kkma?file=src/App.js

Comment: check this out -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ydkjsy

Comment: Tanks a lot! so my mistake was:  value={user}.
Tanks again!

Answer (score 0):

i use coffeescript, you can think the -> as function or =>, if we Passing a parameter to an onClick event handler in functional component by loop:

```coffee
onClick = (n, x) -> ->
    setcheckindex n
    x()
<Boxr onClick={onClick n, x.onClick} /> for x,n in g
```

i have send the loopindex by n, and send a function by x.onClick